# drupal 7 restrict login by ip - Monitor

Tags: web-development, php, security, system-monitor, drupal

We are using a drupal 7, with the module "restrict login by IP".

We restrict by: mail & Ip address.

Our goal is to get "debug log", for Add new row to this table(for monitoring any changes in this rule - for security reason)

Any idea for how to monitor this operation?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a question about recommending software? It seems more a question about how to use a Drupal module, or how to set it to achieve a goal.